# Multitenant single-db compile error

Tags: java, grails, plugins, multi-tenant

I just installed multitenant single-db 0.8.3 but can't compile helloworld example. I have errors on plugin java. May be I am missing some basic setup, but I did not find any more info on doc. See below.

symbol:   class DeleteEvent
  location: class HibernateEventListener
/home/scarpa/Grails/helloworld/target/work/plugins/hibernate-hijacker-0.8.1/src/java/grails/plugin/hibernatehijacker/hibernate/events/HibernateEventListener.java:168: error: cannot find symbol
    public void onAutoFlush(AutoFlushEvent event) throws HibernateException {
                            ^
  symbol:   class AutoFlushEvent
  location: class HibernateEventListener
/home/scarpa/Grails/helloworld/target/work/plugins/hibernate-hijacker-0.8.1/src/java/grails/plugin/hibernatehijacker/hibernate/events/HibernateEventListener.java:172: error: cannot find symbol
    private void publishEvent(String eventName, AbstractEvent event) {
                                                ^
  symbol:   class AbstractEvent
  location: class HibernateEventListener
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
100 errors

They seem error about incomplete classpath, i.e. about basic hibernate library not found, as if grails is not completing correctly classpath during plugin installation... any hint?

Comment: If I comment multitenant single-db plugin inclusion in my config, I got error: svn-1.0.0.M1/lib does not exist !!!

Answer (score 0):

Found another answer on stackoverflow saying that:

Switching back to the:
runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.17"

and changing
cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'

let me to compile correctly; probably hibernate 4 plugin is not installing with correct dependency...